# Apache POI does not generate excel in Linux

Tags: java, linux, excel, tomcat, apache-poi

I have a servlet to download user list as excel as follow

```
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.xls");
    File excelFile = new File(filename);
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
    // ...
    // populate workbook with user list from Database here
    // ...
    workbook.write(response.getOutputStream()); // Write workbook to response.
    workbook.close();
```

this code working in Windows without any issue. But when I try to deploy on Tomcat 7 in ubuntu server, When I execute (download excel), it throws FileNotFoundException. The excel file is not created in webapps/(my application folder), it creates excel file in Windows. 
I've already set tomcat's webapps and it's subdirectories as 777 and changed owner to tomcat7 user.

Apache POI version is 3.10-FINAL

Comment: The above code streams a response, there is no File (in your posted code).

Comment: *"it creates excel file in Windows"* - what do you mean?

Comment: workbook.write(response.getOutputStream()); writes excel as a file under tomcat's webapps/(project) directory, and pass it to response.